# Visual Studio Test results

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, uwp

I'm running a Windows 10 Unit test app in a Jenkins CI environment. I'm able to compile and run the Test App, but there is a way to pipe the results of the tests to a document or something in order to show them in a Dashboard?

To run the tests I use:

```
.\vstest.console.exe
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run the tests that use a post build step to publish the results.

Other plugins may then be used to convert these to be used by other tools.[image: Jenkins Run/Publish MS Test]

Comment: I'm running the tests in a Windows 10 Unit Test App, will try the solution with MSTest